# Unable to pull fields from within LINQ query

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, linq

Quick overview:
  Visual Basic 2010 WinForm app pulls data from DB2.  The app allows users to filter the data.

The problem:
  I'm doing something wrong with my LINQ query (or object definition), as I'm not able to access fields within the dataset.  Pulling data from DB2 is fine, I get that data and store it as an IEnumerable.

I plan to run this app as disconnected since its readonly for 95% of the users and it accesses 100,000+ records.  Because of this, I have two datasets: 1) 'data' which is the full dataset pulled from DB2 (I don't plan on doing any modifications to it), (2) 'filteredData' which is a subset of data based on user entered filters.

```
Dim data As IEnumerable  
Dim dataFiltered = From record in data
                   Select record

'Filter data based on version
Select case uxCodeVersion.Text
  Case "10"
    dataFiltered = From rec in dataFiltered
                   Where rec.
  ... (other parts of case statement removed)
End Select
```

and this is my problem.  I'm expecting to see the list of fields within 'rec.' (such as rec.CodeVersion) ;however, I just receive object methods (Equals, GetHashCode, GetType, ReferenceEquals, ToString).

What simple thing am I missing?

Performance is an issue too, but I figured one problem at a time...

Thank you,
Brian.

Here is the answer as provided below.

When defining data, I need to define it to the generic list DTO.  So in my case, that becomes:

```
    Dim data As IEnumerable(Of DataAccessLayer.DiagnosisAndDiagnosisIndustryCombinedDTO)
```

Then when accessing the code, its the same as before, though I temporarily took out the dataFiltered field and just used data.

```
dataFiltered = From rec in data
               Where rec.CodeVersion = uxCodeVersion.Text
```

Comment: how are you initializing `data`?

Comment: It varies by what the user selects from a combo box.  The app allows for 4 tables to be read, with an additional 2 options being for a JOIN of those tables.  In either case, the DataAccessLayer is creating a List (of T) in which "T" is determined by the table being accessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code sample, you define data as IEnumerable. From your comment you say that your data layer returns a List(of T),

While the assignement of List(of T) to IEnumerable is valid, the type contained in the IEnumerable is Object. That's why you don't get intellisense.

You should either declare IEnumerable(of T), or do something like:

```
Dim data = datalayer.GetFoo()
```

This will cause type inference and you'll get intellisense.

Comment: Thank you, this worked.  Unfortunately, its going to cause me to add additional code, but I'm very glad to have it answered.  The additional code is because I have 6 tables, so instead of using one 'data' field, now I have to use 6 of them so that they can each specify the correct type of list.  My intent was to reduce code and use one 'data' field to encompass all DTOs.  For some reason, I thought the Generic List would let me do that, but I must be remembering it incorrectly.  Thank you again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Until you assign a type to IEnumerable, you won't be able to access the fields in this way. For example (c#): `IEnumerable<YourType>` should work.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Also a correct answer, but mrlucmorin contained additional information that helped me to fix my issue.